# Question about a dimension in this IC package drawing

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, datasheet, pcb-fabrication, packages

this is the first time I'm making a PCB layout, so I'm not too familiar with datasheets. The picture below shows a diagram for an IC I'm using. The datasheet says all dimensions are in mm.  However, near the bottom you can see a number that has 0.25 with a circled M, followed by an A and C. What do these letters mean? And does that mean the hole size is 0.25 mm for a pin? I'm really confused because I know it can't be 0.25mm.
Is that in mils instead?

[image]

Comment: Circled M = MMC = Maximum Material Condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read more about those symbols in this [Drafting Manual](http://www.draftingzone.com/shoppingzone/6-1.pdf) but those particular symbols are related to the tolerance rather than size:

[image: Tolerance symbols]

It seems to me the seven pins have a diameter of 0.6 mm +/- 0.1mm with a spacing of 1.27 mm between them. It's quite common for dimensions to be prefixed by "7 x" etc to indicate the same dimension applies to multiple items.